# SQL Server Integrated Security (Windows Authentication)

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, integrated-security

I have a question about Windows Authentication on SQL Server.

If I give my database to anyone, will they still be able to access it using Integrated Security?

Because it seems like if I move my database from one machine to another, I am still able to access it using Integrated Security. Does this mean anyone can access it using Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) if I give them the file?

EDIT:
I'm just curious because I was working on my SQL Server file (.mdf) then I moved it to another machine and I was still able to access it using Windows Authentication

EDIT:
Its an MDF file which I attach

Comment: Unclear of the motive?

Comment: Is this a "contained" database or a regular MDF file that you detach/attach? How are you accessing it now: do you have a Login mapped to your Windows Login OR is there a Login mapped to a Windows Group?

Comment: Its and MDF file and I access it using Visual Studio. Does this mean when I finally deploy it to the customers I can simply leave it at "Windows Authentication"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on this new machine you are logged into SQL Server and are, through any one of various means, a member of the `sysadmin` role, then absolutely you will have access to it. Anyone who is a member of the `sysadmin` role will have access to it.

For people who authenticate via Integrated Security / Trusted Connection and who are not `sysadmin`, then if there a User in the DB that is linked to a Login (in SQL Server) that is based on a Windows Group, then anyone in that Windows Group will still have access as long as the MDF is attached to an instance that is part of the same network such that the Security ID (SID) for that Windows Group is the same as the one listed in the database that connects that User to the Login (in [master]).

When using LocalDB, "deploying" to the customer will entail that they have an instance of LocalDB on their PC and you will attach this DB. They would be sysadmin on their local instance of LocalDB and as such should have access to any databases that are attached. Just keep in mind that the instance of LocalDB is **per-windows-Login** so only that Login on that PC will have the instance of LocalDB that has your database on it. It can be "shared" with others, but you would need to set that up separately.

However, the best way to know if this plan will or will not work is to try it out. Deploy your database to a coworkers PC and see if they (not you) can access the database. That is a better indication of what will happen then any answer here could give ;-). Even better would be to "deploy" it to a computer that is not even part of your network (which is the essentially the same scenario as the customer's PC would be, right?).

Comment: Let us say i am working on the file in Visual Studio; when I'm finished and I finally want to deploy it to the customer, do i have to setup a password or I can leave the connection string as "Integrated Security"?

Comment: @MunasheTsododo That depends on how your app is set up. Is this LocalDB? If you deploy to a customer's system (local pc or server) such that they are sysadmin on that instance, they have access.

Comment: I am attaching it to localdb

Comment: Yes its localdb @srutzky

Comment: @MunasheTsododo I updated my answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly odd question - if you give someone your DB (however you do this) and have them set this up on a SQL server that they administer, then yes, they will have rights to access it.

If your database is then accessed by your application, you will need for them to set up the appropriate accounts to access the database as per their requirements.

Comment: So let us say I am working on an MDF file, when I finally deploy it to the customers I can simply leave it at "Windows Authentication"?

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know yes. If you give other you database, thy can always take ownership of the database and edit his permissions